# linq to entities how to create database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm new to linq to entities.

In linqtosql you could do something like:

datacontext.CreateDatabase() to generate a database from the model in sql.

I'm wanting to do the same thing in linq to entities.

Say I have a class MyEntities which inherits from ObjectContect is there a similiar method?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Create a builder and configure it 
var builder = new ContextBuilder<MyContext>(); 
…

// Create a context 
var mycontext = builder.Create(sqlConnection);

// Prepare the Context 
if (!myContext.DatabaseExists()) 
   myContext.CreateDatabase();
```

**Reference:** http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/12/tip-32-how-to-create-a-database-from-ssdl-ef-4-only.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ModelBuilder class, there is a CreateModel method you can call on that.